# Bash script to move duplicate files with different extension?

Tags: bash

Tidying up music folder:

```
song1.mp3,
song2.mp3,
song3.mp3,
song3.m4a,
song4.mp3,
song5.m4a
```

How do I get rid of files with the same name but different extension - in this example song3.

Comment: You haven't explained by which criterion a duplicate should be deleted. Is it arbitrary? The smallest file? Biggest file? Prefer MP3s over M4As? Some other complex criterion? Random?

Answer (score 1):

I have a script that does this and specially for you I've added comments! ;-)

Note that my script checks for equivalent names and doesn't check anything further. Make sure you have a backup if my script doesn't work for you.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
  
declare -a known
usage="Usage: $0 mp4"
extension=${1?$usage}

if [[ $extension =~ ^-h ]]; then
        echo $usage
        exit 0
fi

function move_file {
        local f="${1?No file given in ${FUNCNAME[0]}}"
        local d="${2?No dir given in ${FUNCNAME[0]}}"

        # Check if directory exists
        [[ -d "${d}" ]] || mkdir "${d}"
        mv "${f}" "${d}/."
}

while read -r file; do
        # Extract the filename without extension
        name="$(basename "${file%\.*}")"

        # Create entry if it doesn't exist
        if ! [[ "${known[$name]+test}" ]]; then
                known[$name]="$file"
                continue
        fi


        # Extract the extension from the filename
        dir="${known[$name]##*.}"

        # Check if previous found file
        if [[ ${known[$name]} != ok ]] && [[ ${dir} != ${extension} ]]; then
                move_file "${known[$name]}" "$dir"
                known[$name]="$file"
        fi

        # Retain files with extension on current location
        dir="${file##*.}"
        if [[ ${dir} != ${extension} ]]; then
                read -p "Do you want to keep $file? (Y/n)" q
                [[ $q != 'n' ]] || continue
                move_file "$file" "$dir"
                known[$name]=ok
        fi

done <<< "$(find . -type f)"
exit 0
```

Output

```
$ find
.
./a.txt
./b.txt
./test.sh
./a.sh
./a.mp3
$ ./name_clean.sh mp3
$ find
.
./sh
./sh/a.sh
./b.txt
./test.sh
./txt
./txt/a.txt
./a.mp3
```

Comment: works fine on example but I had to change line 3:
declare -a known

Comment: but in real music folder script breaks in line 26 (invalid arithmetic operator or syntax error in expression) most likely because filenames contain ()'& and spaces

Comment: @dreamwebspace I've updated it a bit. Wrap variables with `"` until the script works. Perhaps accept my answer if I ended up helping you ;-)

Comment: it's extracting loosing 1st word

Comment: ./duplicate.sh: line 26: bad mice bombscare: syntax error in expression (error token is "mice bombscare")

Comment: Try to debug it by adding "-x" to the shebang: `#! /bin/bash -x`. It seems tat the line `[[ "${known[$name]+test}" ]]` fails somehow.

Comment: I think it's due to `$name` not being enclosed with `"`. Try `[[ "${known["$name"]+test}" ]]` and apply it to every other variable that can hold a filename :-)

Comment: It didn't help. syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator